# groovy: how to escape "(" regex etc in textarea?

Tags: regex, groovy, escaping

I have some text area field in my grails application.  I got the following errors:

.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 36 Name:  note: 1) data listing ....

how could i escape the regular expressions in the text area field?

thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The same as in a literal: place a backslash before it:

```
\(
```

**EDIT:** But if none of the characters from the text area must be treated special, try:

```
String escapedContents = java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(textArea.getText());
```

Comment: the problem is my client does not want to write "\\(" in the note field which is a textArea field.  People like to write 1).  something; 2).  good stuff; 3) ok.......

how could I let my client write frieely without crashing my program?

thanks!!!!!!